# Moving 2tb (150 Million+) items from one s3 bucket to another in a reasonable time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am wondering what tools are available for such a task. I wrote a multithreaded script, but it is too slow. I prefer a native solution, over a 3rd party one. Because of the contents of this bucket, I cannot risk running 3rd party tools on it.

This is an intra region transfer (us-east-1)

Comment: Is it cross region or within one region? Intra-region transfers have different constraints.

What are your constraint on usage of 3rd party tools. Apart from using the AWS CLI, you would probably be limited to software you wrote yourself.

Comment: This is an intra-region transfer

Comment: The normal S3 API should be more than enough for you. You could take a look at https://github.com/CologneBroadcastingCenter/s3-backup-restore/blob/add_s3backuprestore_module/s3backuprestore/backup.py for some insights into a working high performance copying script. Full disclosure: I am a collaborator on that repository.

Comment: How long can I expect to do it with the S3 CLI API (if that is what you are referring to)?

Comment: How fast would something like aws s3 sync be?

Comment: I'd try it - that should be S3 to S3 with no temporary storage in the middle.  In theory you couldn't get any faster.  You'll use something like `aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destbucket`